# Flutter The type parameter is not nullable: null

Tags: flutter, dart

On the line `await Future<int>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));` the error `The type parameter is not nullable: null` is thrown.

```
Future<dynamic> createSomething() async {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
  );
  await Future<int>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      createSomething();
    },
    child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The return type of the function is `dynamic` and you don't return anything,
Declare the type of the function as `Future<void>`

also write `Future.delayed` not `Future<int>.delayed` as this future also returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

remove `<int>` i think it's worked or use `<dynamic>` like this

```
await Future<dynamic>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
```

or like that

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
```